# Android PhoneGap - numeric keyboard only

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using the following code in my project and it's working fine:

["How to show and hide soft keyboard in Android"](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/27915465/How%20to%20show%20and%20hide%20soft%20keyboard%20in%20Android)

However, I would like to replace the keyboard with the "number" keyboard. I don't want it globally, so I'm guessing I won't have to edit the xml file. It should only be numeric when I call it from the javascript.

Comment: link is broken, here the new: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/How-to-show-and-hide-soft-keyboard-in-Android

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get any kind of Keyboard when you tap an input depending on its type

For a numeric keyboard, you need to set its type to number

```
<input type="number" name="txtNumber"/>
```

Comment: I'd like to initiate the KB without tapping. It's working so far, but not showing the "number" keyboard.

Comment: When a page loads, I'd like the keyboard to show so that all the user has to do is enter a dollar amount. The keyboard is working but, it's showing the default keyboard. I'd like to change that to the decimal keyboard. The instructions in my first link work perfectly, but there's no info on how to customize.

Comment: Be careful with this.  We found out, the hard way, that if your z-index gets messed up the input field will revert back to the original android keyboard.  Thank JQuery mobile for this one

Comment: but where  set the inputvtype

Comment: @xximjasonxx: thanks for the hint, had the same issue and was going insane.

Comment: @xximjasonxx how does the s-index get messed up?  Is something overlaying the input or is it just not set?  I tried setting the z-index to a large number, setting position to relative and I still can't get the number keyboard to show up when i do a $("input").focus().  Any ideas?

Comment: @TitouandeBailleul some models of phones (such as some *galaxy*, f.e. my *galaxy s4 mini*) bring the numeric keyboard but without dot sign so in this way impossible to input decimal value there...

Answer (score 12):

The Tel type brings in a Numerical keyboard like in dial mode.

```
<input type="tel" name="txtNumber"/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

only put type "tel" works for me in Cordova.

```
<input class="textbox-container" type="tel" name="identification" id="identification">
```